# Aspose referenced fonts

Tags: aspose, aspose.words

Is copying text from word to another word copy too the referenced fonts which are not used? If yes is there is a way to detect only the used fonts without iterating the whole paragraph?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to iterate through the Run nodes to get the information about really used fonts in the document. Please use the following code to get the desired information.

```
 NodeCollection runs = dstDoc.GetChildNodes(NodeType.Run, true);

 foreach(Run run in runs) {
  Console.WriteLine("Font Name: {0}", run.Font.Name);

 }
```

Hope, this helps.

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Aspose.Words copy too the referenced fonts which are not used. Please use the following code to get information about all fonts used in document.

```
Document doc = new Document(MyDir + "Document.doc");

FontInfoCollection fonts = doc.FontInfos;
int fontIndex = 1;

// The fonts info extracted from this document does not necessarily mean that the fonts themselves are
// used in the document. If a font is present but not used then most likely they were referenced at some time
// and then removed from the Document.
foreach (FontInfo info in fonts)
{
    // Print out some important details about the font.
    Console.WriteLine("Font #{0}", fontIndex);
    Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", info.Name);
    Console.WriteLine("IsTrueType: {0}", info.IsTrueType);
    fontIndex++;
}
```

Hope, this helps.

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: Of course there is no need, I am asking if it copy or no?

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/165483) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Yes, Aspose.Words copy too the referenced fonts which are not used.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but please read my full question, I asked if yes how to know the fonts which are really used not including the referenced ones